# Java - Oracle SQL - SQL comamnd not properly ended

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I have this code in my Java application:

```
String query = "select name from BusinessRuleType where businessRuleTypeId = "+id+";";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Now when I execute this from my Oracle SQL Developer, (the code: `select name from BusinessRuleType where businessRuleTypeId = 5;` then I'll get results.

My Eclipse gives me this error;

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:766)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1244)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:420)
at persistence.tool.ToolDAO.getOperator(ToolDAO.java:106)
at persistence.tool.ToolDAO.getAll(ToolDAO.java:40)
at persistence.tool.ToolService.getAll(ToolService.java:11)
at controller.Controller.getAllRules(Controller.java:29)
at servlets.ExecuteServlet.doGet(ExecuteServlet.java:18)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is wrong with my code in Java, or is it maybe better to work with a prepared statement and would this fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to remove the last semicolon

```
String query = "select name from BusinessRuleType where businessRuleTypeId = "+id;
```

Comment: @Ivaro18:- On a side note, your code is prone to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try to use [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in future :)

Comment: thanks but it's for a school project, security is not important yet

Comment: @Ivaro18:- Just added to inform you about the best practice ;). You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "+id use java.sql.PreparedStatement

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html